# Why do I get a run-time error when I run a WebBrowser control on another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, browser

**Unhandled exception at 0x0e90a1c0 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.**

Based in the post [How might I create and use a WebBrowser control on a worker thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995527/how-might-i-create-and-use-a-webbrowser-control-on-a-worker-thread/) I'm trying to run the `WebPagePump` class on another thread.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { WebNav1(); });
    t.Start();
}

private Action WebNav1 = delegate()
{
    WebPagePump a = new WebPagePump();
    a.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com"));
    a.Completed += delegate(WebBrowser wb)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's loaded!");
            a.Dispose();
        };
};
```

Comment: Looks familiar.  The point of WebPagePump was to *not* have to start your own thread.  Get rid of `new Thread`, post the stack trace if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a Single Threaded Apartment:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { WebNav1(); });
t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
t.Start();
```

Comment: It may fix the problem but this is not a particularly helpful answer. **Why** do you need a Single-Threaded Apartment?

Comment: Because this is the threaduing model for UI controls. Part of the ActiveX specifications for legacy reasons. And guess waht the webbrowser control internally is - IE ;) An ActiveX control. This is standard windows control knowledge for 20 years and still one of those questions to weed out seniors from juniors, sadly.

Comment: +1. To answer your comment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8xdz5c.aspx "Windows Forms uses the single-threaded apartment (STA) model because Windows Forms is based on native Win32 windows that are inherently apartment-threaded. The STA model implies that a window can be created on any thread, but it cannot switch threads once created, and all function calls to it must occur on its creation thread"

Comment: t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA; don't resolve problem.

I tried try it before and now again.

The problem is not exactly with multithreading instances of ActiveX .net IE WebBrowser class. Because it's works fine!
It's about Completed event calling, if implemented an Access violation rises and Visual Studio close the application under svhost.exe

Thank you all