# Run and control browser control in different thread

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have my main gui class with some subclassess. There are +- 3 threads that are collecting data from various internet sources and API gateways etc.

Now, out of one of these threads, I want to run a webbrowser control, so I can add some autobrowsing functionality to my program. Each of the sub threads should be capable of opening a webbrowser on its own. So I created a second c# windows form, which contains only the webbrowsing control.

I already use the ApartmentState.STA setting on this new thread for the webbrowser control. However, the form2 is unresponsive.

I tried to call Application.Run(); from this thread, and this makes the webbrowser/form2 responsive. But then my main thread stops running.

So I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed. Is what I want possible at all ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebBrowser Control in a new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread)

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
var th = new Thread(() =>
{
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler completed = null;

    using (WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
    {
        completed = (sndr, e) =>
        {
            //Do Some work

            wb.DocumentCompleted -= completed;
            Application.ExitThread();
        };

        wb.DocumentCompleted += completed;
        wb.Navigate(url);
        Application.Run();
    }
});

th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
th.Start();
th.Join();
```

that said, I would use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) together with [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to download and parse html resources

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this. It's not just to download content, I also need to automatically select certain buttons and click them etc. Is WebClient still advisable then ?

Comment: Selenium works very well. Only downside is that you need to run a java server component and you have some annoying command prompt windows... But it works :)

Comment: The answer above also works, but it gets a bit cumbersome when I need to browse to a page, enter data, click a button, browse to another page, search for data etc. The dcoumentCompleted events give me headaches then.

Comment: You are god. Spent the whole day on this.

Comment: Would it be possible to execute javascript with this as well?

Comment: I was facing a similar problems and wrote a wrapper for the .NET WebBrowser to abstract away the message loop issues and make the interaction less cumbersome for more involved scenarios. For anyone else whose interested in a fairly simple headless browser for .NET I posted the code to GitHub and made it available via nuget, for more information see https://github.com/LeastOne/WebBrowserWaiter

Comment: @L.B, this is good working way, but unfortunatelly after 3 navigations it doesn't free the memory, before - 15MB, after - 50 MB. IE - 11. I have tried GC.Collect and navigating to "about:blank", but it didn't help.

Comment: @L.B, What to do if I need after DocumentCompleted navigate to another link and use another DocumentCompeteHandler