# Build HTMLDocument from string of HTML

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack, dom

I would like to build a HTMLDocument from a string of HTML.

I already have a large amount of code that parses and uses the HTMLDocument, so I don't want to turn back now. But now I've gone back and used HTMLAgilityPack to get the HTML instead of a WebBrowser (because you can't open a page and load the document in another Thread since the WebBrowser locks up my application. So I switched to the agility pack). 
   So I would like to build a regular System.Forms.HTMLDocument using the string of HTML that I obtained using the HTMLAgilityPack.

Is there a way to build a System.Forms.HtmlDocument from a string of HTML?

Comment: So what's your question? (Have you tried something?)

Comment: You may want to see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059752/run-and-control-browser-control-in-different-thread)

Comment: I edited the question to clearly state my question.

Comment: What's wrong with assigning `WebBrowser.DocumentText`?

Comment: Best solution is to use `LoadHtml` method https://html-agility-pack.net/from-string

Answer (score 4):

How about using [HtmlDocument.Write()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method this way :

```
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
doc.Write("put html string from HTMLAgilityPack here");
```

[HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't expose public constructor, it is embedded in `WebBrowser`. So, you'll still need to have a `WebBrowser` control.