# c# console application WebBrowser ReadyState never complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I use WebBrowser to scrap data from some web page which has javascript loading last 5-8 seconds. the (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) never happen. How could that be?

```
public static String data { get; set; }
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pathToWrite = @"C:\ABC.csv";
    string nodelist = @"C:\WebPagelist.txt"; //{"001", "abc.com/mvc/001" /r/n "002", "abc.com/mvc/002" /r/n "003", "abc.com/mvc/003" /r/n ... "499", "abc.com/mvc/499"}
    string line;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nodelist, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] node = line.Split('\t');
            Download(node[0], node[1]);
        }
    }
    using (var PlayerFile = new StreamWriter(pathToWrite, true))
    {
        PlayerFile.Write(data);
        PlayerFile.Flush();
    }
}
static void Download(string cityName, string url)
{
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate(url);

    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
         Application.DoEvents();
    }
    string A = wb.Document.GetElementById("cur_A").InnerText;
    string B = wb.Document.GetElementById("cur_B").InnerText;
    string C = wb.Document.GetElementById("cur_C").InnerText;
    data  += A + "," + B +"," + C + + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059752/run-and-control-browser-control-in-different-thread

Comment: I see `asp.net` and `console-application` tagged, but this seems like a WinForms application. You should do a `Debug.WriteLine(wb.ReadyState)` and a `Thread.Sleep(100)` for debugging purposes inside that `while` loop. This may also be rewritten to make use of the `wb.DocumentCompleted` event and block the thread it until that event occured (preferably open a new thread / task for that)