# Multithreading - wait until object is initialized?

Tags: c#, multithreading, webbrowser-control

Code in the main thread:

```
browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
Thread subthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(testfn));
subthread.Start();
```

Thread:

```
void testfn(){
    string lastttl="";
    while (true) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        if (browser == null) continue;
        browser.Invoke(new Action(() => ttlstr = browser.Document.Title));
        if (ttlstr != lastttl) { lastttl = ttlstr; MessageBox.Show("title changed to: '" + ttlstr + "'"); }
    }
}
```

testfn() then calls browser.Invoke. I wasn't expecting this to be a problem since browser = new ... should block until the object is created (..right?), but I'm still getting a NullReferenceException.

- browser is initially set to null
- checking browser==null in the second thread also throws a null reference exception
- adding while(browser==null){System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);} before launching the thread doesn't help either

Comment: I would look into using the Parallelism class provided by Microsoft to help manage this type of stuff. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You aren't showing us enough. There's no way checking a local for `null` will throw a `NullReferenceException`. Where is the code for `testfn`

Comment: W>hat is the code of testfn

Comment: updated with testfn code

Comment: your code isn't likely to work. (1- Running a UI thread in a different thread is tricky. 2)  Using a loop for waiting for something has happened should be last resort)  Instead,  use `webBrowser1.DocumentTitleChanged` event

Comment: There are others ways in which I need to access the browser object though (getElementsByTagName, etc) for which there are no events. The code actually does work if I just add a Sleep(5000) at the beginning of the thread. Not a great solution though

Comment: See for ex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059752/run-and-control-browser-control-in-different-thread