# Autologin and parsing on webpage with javascript

Tags: c#, java, php, ruby, automated-tests

I need to login and parse, then insert data to some web page. I know php, ruby, java, c#. In ruby I know mechanize - it's emulating webbrowser, without starting it. Is good for me, but it didn't work with page's with js.

Also I tried with watir - but it is only desktop-based app, because it runs ibrowser.

Are there any other solutions with js, but without starting browser on php, ruby, java, c# to put it on server?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET: [Headless browser for C# (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net)

An interesting headless browser implementation exists for node js (server side javascript) http://zombie.labnotes.org/

Just search for <[programming language], headless browser>

Comment: @brabertaser1992 - A "headless browser" means the browser's UI is never loaded only the page parsing and script rendering engine like webkit V8 is loaded.