# How to update viewsource of the webpage dynamically in .net

Tags: c#, html, webclient, downloadstring

There is one website named "www.localbanya.com", i wanted to grab the HTML information from that site, they list products, the structure of their display is:

1. First they display some around 8-10 products on page-load, and
2. later when user scrolls down it generates more products.

Now as this is happening based on javascript, i am not able to get the whole page source using WebClient.

I wanted to know is there any way i can update the page-source while using WebClient class in .net to retrieve whole page information or any other alternative i can use to get the whole page HTML information, at once.

You can refer this for reference [localbanya product page](http://www.localbanya.com/products/Breakfast---Health-Food/Breads---Bakery/173/170)

Any help will be a appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient obviously doesn't run the JavaScript.

So you're going to need some sort of a **headless browser** to do it.

There are many options for it, though I don't know any C# or .NET implementation.

You may look into [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) and other headless browsers which replicate what a normal browser does and you can write scripts for it.

Also refer to this question: [Headless browser for C# (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net)

You can also run something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what requests were made from the page when scrolling down, to reverse engineer how the data is retrieved, and replicate that with a `WebClient` if possible.