# Is there a way to get the final page after rendering from code in C#?

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to get data from a website an C#:

https://www.trendyol.com/TRENDYOLMiLLA---Trend-Kombinler/ButikDetay/168286

It looks like this website gets the data from an ajax call after the page loads. When I call this code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    return client.DownloadString(URL);
}
```

It gets the base HTML but does not process the ajax call and fill in the data. Is there a way to get the final page after rendering from code?

Comment: Final page of what? And how do you suppose commented out code is supposed to relate? Please read the help on asking questions starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need a headless browser to actually call all javascript code within the page. There already is [a topic on headless browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net), so you might want to check that one first.