# Render SPA using ASP.NET C# (without NodeJS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, server-side-rendering

I need to render (or create snapshots) of an AngularJS/Angular app using only ASP.NET and C#. There are several ways to accomplish server side rendering of SPA's, for example using Angular Universal or third party services like Prerender.io and SEO4AJAX. Unfortunately, due to hosting limitations, i can't use any solution that is based on NodeJS (or that needs to be installed in the server) and my client doesn't want to use any third party services (if possible).

Is it possible to completely render an Angular app (HTML + JS) using ASP.NET and C#? If so, how can i accomplish such task?

Extra info: The app will be hosted on Windows Server with IIS and its services will be developed using ASP.NET Web API 2.

**UPDATE: I just want to render the Angular app for SEO and Social Network purposes and not to generate a file from the page (i.e., Image or PDF). I want to render it in the server the when the user first accesses the page or forces a refresh.**

Comment: You need a (headless) web browser.

Comment: I've updated my question.  Can you further explain how i can use a headless web browser for this issue? Any .NET package that you can indicate that would help me achieve my goal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net