# Headless 'browser' solution without delivering the browser

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, cefsharp, headless

So, I want to automate actions on my website (including some Javascript execution and XPath element findings, performing click/type events) but the thing is that I don't want the endpoint users to install any third party software.

Been looking through many solutions and found out that [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) would be a great solution for my needs, however:

It *does require* endpoint user to have Google Chrome / Firefox browser installed in case of using chrome/firefox driver that support headless browsing.

So I kept searching and found [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) which would embed the browser into my application. That however, it's really a boilerplate solution without the ability to find elements by XPath and compared to selenium is less functional.

**My question is**:
Are there any other solutions (for `C#`) for having a *functional* headless browser, without requiring the endpoint user to have the browser installed so that I could deliver my binary as a ready to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headless browser for C# (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161413/headless-browser-for-c-sharp-net)

Comment: @mjwills Given solutions are headless but not browser-independent meaning that I'm still required to deliver the browser myself.

Comment: Which browser is Optimus dependent on?

Comment: @mjwills None. It has only a `Jint` dependency (JS execution engine). However, there is lack of info about `Optimus` around, it looks like it's not being updated anymore and have no documentation whatsoever.

Comment: Is PhantomJS an option?

Comment: @mjwills Sure, I think it would be great to use along with Selenium, however the development of PhantomJS has been [discontinued](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE).

Comment: @DonaldDuck You could use a **portable version of chrome** instead of the local installation, and package it with your application to use selenium with.

Comment: @PixelEinstein Interesting. Might be unsafe though since I don't think there is an official source of portable version of chrome?

Comment: For reference you can use Selenium with CefSharp

Comment: @amaitland That would basically be the same choice as using Selenium with Chromium (Chromium supports `--headless` switch as well)

Comment: I am aware of this, I'm simply telling you what's possible.

Comment: @amaitland Any idea if I could use CefSharp with conditional `--headless` flag? I mean, for debug, I would like it to run normally but in release I'd like to pass the `--headless` switch to it.

Comment: You can use the OffScreen version and still open devtools or add your own command line arg and show a WPF window, it uses the same rendering engine as the OffScreen version.

Comment: @amaitland You mean the OffScreen version would be able to output in the WPF window too?