# Terminating Thread Running an Event

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, thread-safety, webbrowser-control

I wrote an [API](https://github.com/0014/Tribal-Wars-API) that automates a certain website. However, on the testing stage, I noticed that (not very sure), my thread is not being terminated correctly.

I am using the `WebBrowser` object to navigate inside a thread, so that it works synchronously with my program:

```
private void NavigateThroughTread(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Defining thread...");

    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {   
        _wb = new WebBrowser();
        _wb.DocumentCompleted += PageLoaded;
        _wb.Visible = true;
        _wb.Navigate(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Web browser navigated.");
        Application.Run();
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Thread defined.");

    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

    Console.WriteLine("Before thread start...");
    th.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread started.");

    while (th.IsAlive) { }
    Console.WriteLine("Journey ends.");
}

private void PageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pages loads...");
    .
    .
    .
    switch (_action)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        case ENUM.FarmActions.Idle:
           _wb.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));
           _action = ENUM.FarmActions.Exit;

           return;

        case ENUM.FarmActions.Exit:
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing wb...");
            _wb.DocumentCompleted -= PageLoaded;
            _wb.Dispose();

            break;
    }

    Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
}
```

Here is how I call this function:

```
public int Attack(int x, int y, ArmyBuilder army)
{
    // instruct to attack the village
    _action = ENUM.FarmActions.Attack;

    //get the army and coordinates
    _army = army;
    _enemyCoordinates[X] = x;
    _enemyCoordinates[Y] = y;

    //Place the attack command
    _errorFlag = true; // the action is not complated, the flag will set as false once action is complete
    _attackFlag = false; // attack is not made yet
    Console.WriteLine("Journey starts");

    NavigateThroughTread(_url.GetUrl(ENUM.Screens.RallyPoint));

    return _errorFlag ? -1 : CalculateDistance();
}
```

So the problem is, when I call the `Attack` function, couple times like this:

```
_command.Attack(509, 355, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(509, 354, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(505, 356, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(504, 356, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(504, 359, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(505, 356, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(504, 356, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
_command.Attack(504, 359, new ArmyBuilder(testArmy_lc));
```

My application most of the times, gets stuck in one of these function (usually happens after the 4th or 5th). When it gets stuck the last log that I see is

> Web browser navigated.

I assume it is something to do with termination of my thread. Can someone show me how I can run a thread which runs the `DocumentCompleted` event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any obvious reason for deadlock, nor did it reproduce at all when testing the code.  There are a number of flaws in the code but nothing that yells "here!" loudly.  I can only make recommendations:

1. Consider that you do not need a thread at all.  The `while (th.IsAlive) { }` hot loop blocks your main thread while you wait for the browser code to finish the job.  That is not a useful way to use a thread, you might as well use your main thread.  This instantly eliminates a large number of potential hang causes.
2. The state logic in PageLoaded is risky.  We cannot see all of it but one glaring issue is that you dispose the WebBrowser twice.  If you have a case where you use `return` without a  Navigate() call then you'll hang as described.  No need to unsubscribe the event but same story, if you do unsubscribe but don't all Application.Exit() then you'll hang as described.  State machines can be hard to debug, thorough logging is necessary.  Minimize the risk by moving the Dispose() call and unsubscribing the event out of the logic, it doesn't belong there.  And you need to test what happens when any Navigate() call ends up in failure, redirecting to a page you did not expect.
3. The `_wb.Dispose()` call is risky.  Note that you destroy the WebBrowser while its DocumentCompleted event is in flight.  Technically that can return code execution to code that is no longer alive or present.  That can trip a race condition in the browser.  As well as in the debugger, there is a dedicated MDA that checks for this problem.  It is trivially avoided by moving the Dispose() call after the Application.Run() call where it belongs.
4. The while-loop burns 100% core, potentially starving the worker thread.  Not a good enough reason to explain deadlock, but certainly unnecessary.  Use Thread.Join() instead.
5. You create a lot of WebBrowser objects in this code.  It is a very heavy object, as you can imagine, you need to keep an eye on memory usage in your program.  Especially the unmanaged kind.  If the browser leaks, like they so often do, you could technically create a scenario where the WB initializes okay but does not have enough memory left to load the page.  Strongly favor using only *one* WB.
6. You need to consider that this might well be an environmental problem.  On the top of that list is forever anti-malware and firewall, they always have a very good reason to treat a browser specially since that is the most common malware injection vector.  You'll need to run your test with anti-malware and firewall disabled to ensure that it is not the cause of the hang.
7. Another environmental problem is one I noticed while testing this code, Google got sulky about me hitting it so often and started to throttle the requests, greatly slowing down the code.  Talk to the web site owner and ask if he's got similar blocking or throttling counter-measures in place, most do.  You need to test your state logic to verify that it still works properly when the browser redirects to an error page.
8. Yet another environmental issue is the WB will display a dialog itself in certain cases.  This can deadlock in 3rd party code, very hard to diagnose.  You should at least set the WebBrower.ScriptErrorsSuppressed to *true* but beware of Javascript code in the web page you load that itself creates new windows or displays alert dialogs.  Using one WB is the workaround.
9. Keep in mind that your program can only be as reliable as your Internet connection and the web page server.  That's not a terribly good place to be of course, both are quite out of your reach and you don't get nice exceptions to help you diagnose such a failure.  And consider that you probably have not yet tested your program well enough yet to check if it can survive such a failure, it doesn't happen enough.

Quite a laundry list, focus first on eliminating the unnecessary thread and temporarily suppressing anti-malware.  That's quick, focus next on using only [one WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995667/17034).

Comment: Thanks very much for your precious feedback ! The first suggestion makes a lot of sense, only if its applicable. Would you be able to show a very simple structure, of waiting the `DocumentCompleted` event on the main thread without using threads ? It doesn't have to be optimized, only it needs to work :)

Comment: You cannot wait, that causes deadlock.  You don't have to wait, your state machine in the DocumentCompleted event handler already takes care of some of it.  You can further enhance it by also working down a list of URLs or Action delegates.

Comment: Yes, the state machine works. However, I am trying to implement an API. I want the client to wait until the operations are made afters the pages are loaded. Therefore, the while loop is intentionally placed inside the code.

Answer (score -1):

Hans thank you, I was able to fix this issue with one of your ideas. As you spent your time giving me a long answer, I wanted respond in same manner.

2 - I built the state machine structure carefully and with a lot logs (you can see it from my [git account](https://github.com/0014/Tribal-Wars-API/blob/master/TribalWars.API/TribalWars.API/Src/FarmActions.cs)) also did a lot of debugs. I am sure that after I'm done navigating, I use `Application.ExitThread()` and `wb.Dispose()` only once.

3 - I tried placing the `wb.Dispose()` outside the event, however I couldn't find any other place where the Thread is still alive. If I try disposing `WebBrowser` outside the thread which is created inside the thread, the application gives me an error.

4 - I changed the code `while (th.IsAlive) { }` with `th.Join(2000)` this is absolutely a better idea but did not change anything. It optimized the code and as you mentioned, it prevented burning 100% core of my CPU.

5 - I tried using a single `WebBrowser` object which is instantiated in the constructor. However when I tried to navigate inside the thread, the application wouldnt even fire the events anymore. For some reason, I couldn't make it running whit a single `WB` object.

6,7 - I tested my application with different PC's and diffrent networks(with firewall and non-firewall protection). I changed windows firewall options as well but no travail. On my original code I do have `_wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` so this shouldn't also be the issue.

8,9 - If these are the reasons, I can't do anything about it. But I doubt the real problem is caused because of them.

1 - This one was a good suggestion. I tried implementing my code without using a thread and it is now working fine. Here is how it looks like (still needs a lot optimization)

```
// Constructer
public FarmActions(string token)
{
    // set the urls using the token
    _url = new URL(token);

    // define web browser properties
    _wb = new WebBrowser();
    _wb.DocumentCompleted += PageLoaded;
    _wb.Visible = true;
    _wb.AllowNavigation = true;
    _wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
}

public int Attack(int x, int y, ArmyBuilder army)
{
    // instruct to attack the village
    _action = ENUM.FarmActions.Attack;

    //get the army and coordinates
    _army = army;
    _enemyCoordinates[X] = x;
    _enemyCoordinates[Y] = y;

    //Place the attack command
    _errorFlag = true; // the action is not complated, the flag will set as false once action is complete
    _attackFlag = false; // attack is not made yet
    _isAlive = true;

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Journey starts");

    NavigateThroughTread(_url.GetUrl(ENUM.Screens.RallyPoint));

    return _errorFlag ? -1 : CalculateDistance();
}

private void NavigateThroughTread(string url)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Defining thread...");
    _wb.Navigate(url);

    while (_isAlive) Application.DoEvents();
}

private void PageLoaded(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pages loads...");
    .
    .
    .
    switch (_action)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        case ENUM.FarmActions.Idle:
           _wb.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));
           _action = ENUM.FarmActions.Exit;

           return;

        case ENUM.FarmActions.Exit:

            break;
    }
    _isAlive = false;
}
```

This is how I was able to wait without using a thread.

The main problem was probably as you mentioned in number 3 or 5. But I wasn't able to fix the problem as I spent couple of hours.

Anyway thanks for your help it works.